# Getting issue in installing python in my widows 7 professional machine

Tags: python, failed-installation, windows-error-reporting

I have installed new windows on my machine and after that, I tried to install python I am getting an error which is attached within the image.

I have searched issue related to this on google and stack overflow also but didn't find relevant results related to my problem.

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your PC meets the system requirements:
Processors: Intel Atom® processor or Intel® Core™ i3 processor.
Disk space: 1 GB.
Operating systems: Windows 7 or later, macOS, and Linux.
Python versions: 2.7.X, 3.6.X.
If you meet the requirements, try re installing python